# Age vertification input box - calculate if over 18 years

Tags: javascript, html, verification

I have an input box where you should put your year of birth in. If the number is below 1998 you should gain access, if it's over 1998 you should go to another page.

I know this could possible be a mixture of javascript and html, but I can't figure out how to make the code and hoped you guys could help me!

This is the action that should happen, if the user is born in 1998 or before:

```
<div  id="btn-close-modal" class="close-modal-03"> 
   CLOSE MODAL
</div>
```

Hope you can help me :-)

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff. I'd suggest following some tutorials on javascript/php. Google is your friend here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32067572/i-need-to-restrict-age-for-below-18-years-age-from-the-current-date-in-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931102/check-on-every-page-to-ensure-user-has-validated-as-being-over-18

Comment: I know it should be pretty basic but I haven't actually found something yet that could help. Rahul Dambare; I have looked at your links, the latest one is pretty close I think, but I'm not able to change it the way I want to.

As stated above, I want an input box - just one - where you type in your birth year, and from that information only it should be able to calculate if you are over 18 when clicking submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using jQuery.

1. Get the year from the input - `$('input').val()`.
2. Get the current year - `new Date().getFullYear()`.
3. Check if the diff between them is larger than 18.

**Like this:**

```js
$('#age_validation_btn').click(function() {
  var age = $('#age_validation_input').val();
  if (new Date().getFullYear() - parseInt(age) >= 18) {
    alert('older than 18');  
  }
  else {
    alert('younger then 18');  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="age_validation_input" /><button id="age_validation_btn">Validate</button>
```

Comment: Some of it works. But no matter what number I put in the input, it says younger than 18?

Comment: I have tried even typing in 1, and it still comes out as younger... Is there some kind of fail in the code? I can see that you have the var age = input, shouldn't the input field itself be connected with that frase?

Comment: Do you want that the user type his **age** or his **birth year**?

Comment: I have made this from your code, but it still only says older than.... I cannot get it to work :(

`<script>
$('button').click(function() {
  var age = $('aar').val();
  var year = 1998;
  if (age < year) {
    alert('older than 18');  
  }
  else {
    alert('younger then 18');  
  }
});
</script>`

Comment: I want the user to enter his birth year

Comment: This is not like my code at all. Try to follow **exactly** my code.

Comment: I have used **exactly** your code, but it did not work. I want the user to type in his birth year.

Comment: A. what is `$('aar')`? it's should be `input`. `aar` is **class** or **id**? B. You need to use `parseInt` to get the input value as **number** so you could compare it with `year` variable.

Comment: But shouldn't the $('input') be connected with the right input? Otherwise it could be any input or what? Shouldn't input have some kind of name or something to be connected with the query code?

Comment: Yes it is. How `aar` related to the input? Just how me how the input html looks like.

Comment: aar is danish for year, so I tried to make a code using your code, and called the input field aar, but it didn't work. Now I'm back to your code but it still doesn't work, it's like the input field and the code is not connected. The html looks like this: `<input type="number" /><button>Validate</button>`

Comment: `<head></head><body>
<input type="number" /><button>Validate</button><br>............................<br><script>$('button').click(function() {
  var age = $('input').val();
  if (new Date().getFullYear() - parseInt(age) >= 18) {
    alert('older than 18');  
  }
  else {
    alert('younger then 18');  
  }
});</script></body>`

Comment: You missed the jquery reference but beside this, it's working http://jsbin.com/yopimu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I can see it working in that link! I just copied it over and it actually doesn't work? I think it has to do with the link to the jquery reference? I actually have a lot of other code, and maybe that does that it is not working?

Comment: I was updated the [bin](http://jsbin.com/yopimu/edit?html,js,output) I added more logs to the code. Can you update your code with those logs and show me the `console` output after you click on the button?

Comment: How do I see the console output?

Comment: Could it be because I have something else on my web page that requires me to have this code? `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-ui?hl=en. You need only one referense to jQuery. If you already have one, don't put the other.

Comment: But the other reference is another? And it is placed in the header?

Comment: Yes, you need only one. And yes, in the header. Is your project in local or can I see it a live?

Comment: Couldn't you tell me at the start that I can see it a live ;) ? I was updated the snippet so it will fit to your site. Update it and let me know.

Comment: Haha sorry! It works perfectly thank you so much for taking the time to help me!

Comment: I am thrilled! It is amazing :-) I could actually use your help with the last part of that code - do you have time? I do not think this will take as long :O

Comment: We can't chatting here. Please contact me via linkedin (in my [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/863110/mosh-feu)) then we could talk about whatever you want.

Comment: I do not have linkedin unfortunately

Comment: Done! I have added you

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to use :::

```
db=new Date("original time string from input field with type date here");
db1=new Date();
var d= db1.getFullYear()-db.getFullYear();
if (d>limit) {alert("decide what to do you are not upto limit");}
```